Generalized entropy of black holes
In the review paper 2006.06872 by Maldacena, in eq.(2.4) they wrote that the total entropy of a black hole and its environment also has a contribution from the quantum fields outside the horizon which suggests that the total or "generalized"
entropy of a black hole is,
\begin{equation}
    S_{gen} = \frac{\text{Area of horizon}}{4 G \hbar} + S_{\rm{outside}}
\end{equation}
where the first term is the Bekenstein-Hawking thermodynamic entropy of the black hole, while $S_{\rm{outside}}$ is the entropy of matter as well as gravitons outside the black hole, in fact, we could say it is the entropy of the rest of the universe outside the black hole.
They then went on to discuss the difference between fine-grained entropies and coarse-grained entropies in section 4 which I already understood. Coarse-grained entropies obey the second law of thermodynamics, i.e., they always increase or stay constant. Eventually, on p. 19, they discussed that the fine-grained entropy $S_{\text{black hole}}$ of a black hole must be bounded above by the Bekenstein-Hawking or thermodynamic entropy of the black hole. That I understood. However, they wrote $S_{\text{black hole}} \leq S_{\text{Bekenstein-Hawking}} = S_{\text{coarse-grained}}$.
My confusion stems from when I saw the plot of the Page curve shown below. Since the black hole formed from a pure state, the fine-grained entropy of the black hole should be equal to the fine-grained entropy of the Hawking radiation. Since the fine-grained entropy of the black hole is bounded by the thermodynamic entropy/Bekenstein-Hawking entropy of the black hole, the fine-grained entropy of the Hawking radiation should also be bounded by this. It means that the fine-grained entropy of the Hawking radiation should go down eventually. The plot of the Page curve is clear to me. However, the statement $S_{\text{Bekenstein-Hawking}} = S_{\text{coarse-grained}}$ is confusing since I'm assuming what they mean by $S_{\text{coarse-grained}}$ is $S_{gen}$ (which is what they have stated) and it cannot decrease, it can only increase or stay constant, while $S_{\text{Bekenstein-Hawking}}$ can decrease as shown in the plot.
Can anyone help interpret $S_{gen}$ precisely and explain why $S_{gen}$ is the coarse-grained entropy of the "black hole" such that $S_{\text{black hole}} \leq S_{\text{Bekenstein-Hawking}} = S_{\text{coarse-grained}}$?


Please focus on one question.

@NorbertSchuch I wrote it in such a way to give people some context of my confusion but then I can summarize my questions. Why call $S_{gen}$ the generalized entropy of a "black hole" if it includes $S_{\rm{out}}$ as the entropy of the rest of the universe? Why call $S_{gen}$ the coarse-grained entropy of "black holes"? Why is $S_{\text{Bekenstein-Hawking}} = S_{\text{coarse-grained}}$?

@Ghoster Thanks for the reminder, I'll edit my post.
